# Convert Animated WebP to Mp4 using ffmpeg

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, webp

I am trying to convert a animated webp file to mp4 using javascript ffmpeg, but not able to do so.

I played around with the command given here to convert mp4 to animated webp https://gist.github.com/witmin/1edf926c2886d5c8d9b264d70baf7379 but I cannot do the reverse of this command to convert animated webp to mp4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not supported by FFmpeg yet:

[#4907: Support decoding animated WebP images](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4907)

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer, this is now easily doable.

```
ffmpeg -i file.webm file.mp4
```