# Animated Webp - change framerate

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, webp, animated-webp

Is there any tool or script for batch converting animated webp images?

I want to create animated thumbnails from my animated webp images:

- resize image size
- reduce quality (lossy compression)
- reduce frame rate

I tried tools like [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org), but they cannot change the frame rate.

Comment: I am not too sure to direct you in the right direction. Though Libvips supports setting the delay in animated gifs: https://github.com/libvips/libvips/issues/1299 And because libvips also supports animated webp, you may give it a try

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to change the framerate, the `webpmux` tool from Google (available as the `webp` package on your Linux OS) can do the job quickly and easily.

First you need to know the current duration interval for the source file - there are several ways to do that, but the `webpinfo` from the same package is maybe the easiest - `webpinfo source.webp` the note the duration listed for the frames.

Then calculate your new desired frame rate - if the source animation had an FPS of 10, it would show a duration of 100. To change it to 25, divide 100ms duration by 2.5 (the  multiplier to go from 10 to 25), which will get you a target duration of 40ms.

Finally run `webpmux -duration 40 source.webp -o destination.webp` to create a copy of the source animation with a changed interhframe duration.

Answer (score 0):

## ffmpeg can't decode animated WebP

See [#4907: Support decoding animated WebP images](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4907).

Use another tool, such as `anim_dump`, to extract the WebP frames. See [How can I convert an animated WebP to a WebM?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1140873) for more info and examples.

Once you have the frames you can use `ffmpeg`.

## Example

10 fps, half size:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i input_%03d.webp -vf "fps=10,scale=iw/2:-1" -quality 25 output.webp
```

To encode WebP, `ffmpeg` must be compiled with `--enable-libwebp`.

---

## resize image size

Use the [scale filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale).

## reduce quality (lossy compression)

- Use the `-quality` option for the encoder libwebp. Range is 0-100. Default is 75.
- Optionally, use the `-preset` option to match the content type.

See `ffmpeg -h encoder=libwebp` for more options and info.

## reduce frame rate

Use the [fps filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps) or the `-r` option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you sure that animated webp images are supported as input files? I installed ffmpeg with this option: “brew install homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg --with-webp“, but it doesn’t work. I have also found this: [decoding of animated webp not supported](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4907)

Comment: @Robert You are correct. I failed to remember this although [I have mentioned that ticket in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68369808/) less than a month ago. I'll change the answer.